# Complication Family support- don't show Complication Family if not supported

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

**I'm wondering how to not show a Complication Family if I'm not supporting it.**

Example: Extra Large watch face

In `ComplicationController.swift`'s `getLocalizableSampleTemplate` and `getCurrentTimelineEntry` methods I just pass in a `handler(nil)` when switching on `complication.family` for Extra Large:

```
 case .extraLarge:
     handler(nil)
```

But that must not be right or all there is to do, because my complication for Extra Large is still able to be chosen:

[image]

But it obviously doesn't work or have any data to show:

[image]

**Does anyone know what I'm missing?** Thanks!

UPDATE:

My `ComplicationController.swift`'s `getComplicationDescriptors`:

```
    func getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void) {
    
    let oneSupported = [
        CLKComplicationFamily.circularSmall,
        .modularSmall,
        .utilitarianSmall,
        .modularLarge,
        .utilitarianLarge,
        .graphicExtraLarge,
        .graphicCircular
    ]
    
    let twoSupported = [
        CLKComplicationFamily.circularSmall,
        .modularSmall,
        .utilitarianSmall,
        .utilitarianSmallFlat,
        .extraLarge,
        .graphicBezel,
        .graphicCircular,
        .graphicCorner,
        .graphicRectangular,
        .modularLarge,
        .utilitarianLarge
    ]
    
    let descriptors = [
        CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: ComplicationIdentifier.height.rawValue, displayName: "Complication 1", supportedFamilies: oneSupported)
        // Multiple complication support can be added here with more descriptors
        ,
        CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: ComplicationIdentifier.price.rawValue, displayName: "Complication 2", supportedFamilies: twoSupported)
    ]
    
    // Call the handler with the currently supported complication descriptors
    handler(descriptors)
}
```

Also here's my `WatchApp.swift` which is using that SwiftUI lifecycle (unless I'm mistaken):

```
struct BlockWatchApp: App {
@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var extensionDelegate

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        NavigationView {
            WatchView()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're building your watchOS App using the SwiftUI lifecycle you set up your supported complications using the `getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void)` method.

To support only certain complications you define which ones you want to support in an array:

```
func getComplicationDescriptors(handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationDescriptor]) -> Void) {
    let descriptors = [
        CLKComplicationDescriptor(identifier: "complication", displayName: "App Name",
                                  supportedFamilies: [CLKComplicationFamily.circularSmall,
                                                      CLKComplicationFamily.graphicBezel])
        // Multiple complication support can be added here with more descriptors/
        // Create a new identifier for each new CLKComplicationDescriptor.
    ]
    // Call the handler with the currently supported complication descriptors
    handler(descriptors)
}
```

This example will only display your complication in the `circularSmall` and `graphicBezel` complications. If you want to support all complications use `.allCases`.

If you're building your App using the watchKit with `AppDelegate` lifecycle then you define your supported complications in the .plist file in the WatchKit Extension. You should see "ClockKit Complication - Supported Families" then you can add or delete your desired complication support.

[image: .plistImage]

Comment: (Giving you the bounty because your answer makes sense and I appreciate the answer)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm happy I could help.

Comment: oooofff finally.... hard to find the plist thing on the web to support older watchos versions... Thank you!

Comment: Thank you!!  I am the last Objective C programmer.  I have been struggling with updating to WatchOS9 and none of my complications were appearing.  The plist!!! Of course.